# Is it possible to decompress zlib data in Apex?

Tags: apex, integration, callout

I have a data provider who is passing base64 encoded zlib blobs to my Salesforce environment.  I will be receiving this data into an Apex controller, and I already know how to convert the base64 string into a blob.

I am curious if there is any way to decompress the zlib blob in the controller itself.

I know there are javascript tools that will decompress the data, but I would prefer to handle this in the controller and let the browser simply display the data.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not likely. Much better to use the existing tools you already know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *might* be able to glean the necessary information from [Zippex](https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex), which provides reading and writing ZIP files using the standard compression algorithms. Please note that bitwise manipulation in Apex is extremely limited, so the performance will be relatively abysmal compared to using a JavaScript solution.